# AlertDialog in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Droid and am trying something which should be so simple that it's driving me insane.

I have a `FragmentActivity`. I want to show a **"Hello World"** `dialog/alert`. Something like this is so simple in `.NET (MessageBox.Show())`, but I can't work it out here. I get a compile error on this line:

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

It's not happy with '`context`' - something to do with the `FragmentActivity` I guess. What should I put in place of context?
Thanks

Comment: Where have you context definied? Maybe try: this.getContext(). And provide the compiler error pls

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()` in place of **context**

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
private void dialogShareAddress() {
final CharSequence[] items = {"Call", "Send Message", "Cancel"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Contact to Costomer");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        String name = items[item].toString();
        if (name.equals("Call")) {
           callToCustomer();
        } else if (name.equals("Send Message")) {
            sendSms();
        } else {

        }

    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Your Message Here");

  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", 
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        //To Do: onPositive Button Click
     }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //To Do: onNegativeButton Click
     }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: This isn't in a fragment. It's in a FragmentActivity... None of the above seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing... none of the suggestions worked. I did this in the end:
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

When I use getActivity() I get an error - The method getActivity() is undefined.

But this is where I am confused... I think I am missing the whole point of the difference between FragmentActivity and a Fragment. As I mentioned this code is in a FragmentActivity which doesn't actually implement getActivity(), or context or getContext().